# MVC and Spring MVC Unit Testing

Tags: java, unit-testing, spring-mvc, model-view-controller, spring-mvc-test

Can i Unit test `MVC` framework using `Spring MVC` Unit testing.. if it is possible, what setup do i need to do?
 I want to do only annotation testing.
 If it's possible. Sorry for a noob question, I'm really having a hard time figuring this out.

Comment: The documentation for it is on the Spring website.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, there is a very good support for testing Spring MVC tier using Spring-MVC test framework - more details [here](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.2.x/spring-framework-reference/html/testing.html#spring-mvc-test-framework) - http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.2.x/spring-framework-reference/html/testing.html#spring-mvc-test-framework

Comment: Not necessarily, you can unit test just the controller by mocking out all its collaborators. DBUnit will come in only if you want to do an end to end integration test from controller down.

Comment: What i mean is, I also need to test DAO.. That should be DBUnit right?